# Refreshing Firebase ID and Refresh Tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, token, refresh

I'm trying to use Google login in my mobile app. But I'm unable to understand Firebase tokens fully.

I read on the docs that ID tokens live for an hour, and refresh tokens live until a major change happens. So how are ID tokens refreshed? Do I need to refresh them from the client (by unpacking the JWT and checking the expiration date)? Or will the SDK automatically refresh when it's expired?

When Google login tokens (id and access) are exchanged with Firebase, you get back auth credentials. Then you need to sign the user into firebase using this credential. I then deleted the Google account. But when I open the app again, the refresh token doesn't seem to be expired. So when will Firebase detect that the Google account is deleted and expire the refresh token?

Comment: A lot of what you're asking I was able to find by doing searches.

Comment: I can't really find a direct answer to "Does Firebase SDK automatically refresh ID token?" in any of those 3 questions. Maybe I'm missing something, but would love if you could link me to something specific that answers that?

Comment: The answer is yes.